# Docker volume file permissions

Tags: docker

I have create a docker container with this command:

```
docker run -d -p 20001:80 -v /home/me/folder1/:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4
```

This container contains scripts which create files and directories in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ folder.

I can see this files on host computer in /home/me/folder1/ folder.

I have tried to open one of this files because i want to write something.

I cannot do that because i do not have write permission on this files. This is because they are owned by root user.

What can i do in order to make this files writable be "me" user ? I want to do that automaticaly

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

you have to do

```
sudo chmod +x nameofscript.sh
```

whit this command execute by master you set this scripts executable for all users

Comment: the problem is not the script but the files which are generated by the script. They are data files and want to read/write them from host computer

Comment: when you create it with the scripts at the end set, sudo chmod 777 -R /nameofthefilesfolder and you give permissions on this files

Comment: There are no way to configure docker and say to docker all generated files in volumes will be owned be "me" user ?

Comment: nope, when docker generate file it recognise by himself files